# Custom error handling for a specific page in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, web-config

On a site I run, I have 404's and 500 errors mapped to redirect to a custom error page for end users; using the following code in my web.config:

```
 ...
 ...

 <system.web>
  <customErrors defaultRedirect="/404/default.aspx" mode="RemoteOnly">

     <error statusCode="404" redirect="/404/default.aspx" />

  </customErrors>

  ...
  ...
```

However, I have one specific page that I do not want redirected; a health check page to make sure the site is 100% operational. I tried setting a location specific custom error handler using the code below in my web.config:

```
 ...
 ...

   </system.web>
  <location path="health.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <customErrors defaultRedirect="" mode="RemoteOnly"></customErrors>
    </system.web>
  </location>
 ...
 ...
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. When I rename health.aspx to something else like badhealth.aspx, then make a request, I expect to get a generic 404 error via the Yellow Screen of Death page. Similarly, by intentionally changing the code to throw an error, I should get 500 error via the YSOD page. In both cases, I end up being redirected to our custom 404 page, rathen then getting a YSOD. Thoughts?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks all,
- Frank

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nevermind, we solved the issue. It seems when you have a location specific customError directive; if you leave the defaultRedirect as "", it will default to the sitewide defaultRedirect URL.

The solution was simply to turn off CustomError handling for this specific path, like so:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="/404/default.aspx" mode="RemoteOnly">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="/404/default.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
<location path="health.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Thanks anyway, Jose.

Comment: How did you do that(disable custom error for a specific path)?